# PowerShell - Top CPU usage for Windows service

Tags: powershell, cpu-usage

I need to get CPU usage in percent for Windows services only, this script gives me output for services non-services, how to filter it to get only Windows services

```
Get-Counter "\Process(*)\% Processor Time" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue `
  | select -ExpandProperty CounterSamples `
  | where {$_.Status -eq 0 -and $_.instancename -notin "_total", "idle"} `
  | sort CookedValue -Descending `
  | select @{N="Name";E={
        $friendlyName = $_.InstanceName
        try {
            $procId = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Service | Where-Object { $_.State -eq 'Running' } | select ProcessID
            $proc = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT ProcessId, ExecutablePath FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = $procId"
            $procPath = ($proc | where { $_.ExecutablePath } | select -First 1).ExecutablePath
            $friendlyName = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($procPath).FileDescription
        } catch { }
       $friendlyName
    }},
    @{N="CPU";E={($_.CookedValue/100/$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS).ToString("P")}} -First 10 | ft -AutoSize
```

Output:

```
Name           CPU  
----           ---  
ninjarmmagent  7,29%
mssense        1,92%
ncplayer       1,15%
sensendr       0,96%
opera          0,58%
audiodg        0,58%
opera          0,38%
opera          0,19%
msedgewebview2 0,19%
msmpeng        0,19%
```

Need to remove non-service processes (opera,msedgewebview2..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this might do the trick:

```
$ServicePIDs = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Service | Where ProcessId -ne 0 | Select Name,DisplayName,ProcessId
$LogicalCPUs = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NumberOfLogicalProcessors
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | Where {($ServicePIDs.ProcessId -contains $_.IDProcess) -and ($_.Name -notmatch "_total|idle")} `
| Select @{N="Name";E={($ServicePIDs | Where ProcessId -eq $_.IDProcess).Name}},@{N="DisplayName";E={($ServicePIDs | Where ProcessId -eq $_.IDProcess).DisplayName}},IDProcess,@{N="CPUPercentUsage";E={($_.PercentProcessorTime/($LogicalCPUs * 100))*100}} | Sort CPUPercentUsage -Descending
```

Comment: it's now not showing service which consumes most of CPU, SQL service in this case

Comment: Is that definitely a service not just a standard executable? Whats that service name as shown in the command: Get-Service ?

Comment: yes MSSQLSERVER service

Comment: ah wonder if its like svchost, where the counters just shows tons of svchost over and over, rather than the individual service name for each one, gonna see if I can maybe get it to output the command line or actual name instead just like svchost over and over

Comment: I went a different route, I have edited my answer above

Comment: that's it !,any way to show service display name ?

Comment: I have added that now in the answer. The deleted comment you had was correct though, it does need the percentage calculating from the PercentProcessorTime, that misled me to believe that it was the percentage, it seems not, as Pime95 stress test came back as as over 1k on the PercentProcessorTime. Did you find a way to convert it to percentage, I'll add it to the answer if so?

Comment: i think i figured it `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | Where {($ServicePIDs.ProcessId -contains $_.IDProcess) -and ($_.Name -notmatch "_total|idle")} | Select @{N="Name";E={get-service -name ($ServicePIDs | Where ProcessId -eq $_.IDProcess).Name| select -ExpandProperty DisplayName}},Description,IDProcess,PercentProcessorTime | Sort PercentProcessorTime -Descending`

Comment: please add it if you can

Comment: I have updated the answer again, based on this page:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12984.understanding-processor-processor-time-and-process-processor-time.aspx

It seems to work as Prime95 came back as near 100% usage

Comment: yes, CPU percentage matches one shown in Task Manager, thank you for your valuable support

Comment: `Get-WmiObject` is deprecated and not available in PowerShell Core. `Get-CimInstance`